# What does output="toHtml" layout.xml mean ? - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, local.xml

I know that when we add `output="toHtml"` to some block, he displays it at the bottom of the page outside the `</html>` but i don't know why, what is his utility and in which case it can be used ?

for exemple:

```
<company_index_index>  
    <block type="company/myblockclass" output="toHtml"/> //What's going to happen here
</company_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output="tohtml"` render the block without any specification.